# How to handle click on extension icon?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to do something like google mail checker does: when user click on icon - we should open some url in new tab, but only if tab with that url haven't been opened within tabs.

Help me please, how to do that easily.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Define a [Browser action](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/browserAction.html) in the manifest
2. Attach an event listener to [`chrome.browserAction.onClicked`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/browserAction.html#event-onClicked).
3. Open a new tab using the [`chrome.tabs.create`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-create) method. You can loop through all tabs to check for the existence of the URLs with [`chrome.windows.getAll`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/windows.html#method-getAll).

Comment: I've been trying to do this, but I don't need any popup. And to refine question: how to do it without popup.. I haven't been able to do this, unfortunately.

Comment: @InviS Don't specify the `"default_popup"` entry in the manifest file.

Comment: but where set javascript? I've tried to set it as background script, but it didn't work... And how to answer you directly with \@? like @InviS

Comment: `"background": { "scripts": ["bg.js"] }` works for me. And also first example in the list (http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/samples.html) was very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this snippet. It checks whether a tab containing the URL (or optional match pattern) is already opened. If it is, the tab is focused and URL loaded in it. If not, new tab is opened:

```
function reuseTab(url, match) {
    if (url) {
        var match = match || url;
        chrome.tabs.query({url : match}, function (foundTabs) {
            if (foundTabs[0]) {
                chrome.tabs.update(foundTabs[0].id, {active : true, url : url});
            } else {
                chrome.tabs.create({url : url});
            }
        });
    }
}
```

You can see usage examples and detailed comments with explanation at GitHub:

https://github.com/fczbkk/chrome-extension-snippets/blob/master/js/reuse-tab.js